# Laravel 5 - Get Package Config

Tags: php, laravel, config, laravel-5

Normally we can get config via something like this:

```
$value = Config::get('app.timezone');
```

If want to get the config in the package, we can do something like this:

```
$value = Config::get('package::configfile')
```

How can I link the config file in my package so that I can use it that way?

Comment: It is here within the documentation [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/packages#package-configuration)

Comment: @MattBurrow How 'bout laravel 5? There is no workbench.

Comment: [Here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/packages#configuration) in the laravel 5 section, there is the vendor set of commands which does what workbench does.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure to read the [Package Development](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/packages) chapter in the documentation.

In Laravel 5 there are no config "namespaces" anymore. You just load your config like this in the Service Provider:

```
$this->publishes([
     __DIR__.'/path/to/config/file.php' => config_path('package/file.php'),
]);
```

And access it like this:

```
Config::get('package.file');
```

or:

```
config('package.file');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I tried to put `$this->mergeConfigFrom(
    __DIR__.'/config/file.php', 'package'
);` into service provider's register method and try to access it with `config('package.file');` but it returns nothing. What shall be done to access the config from package directly? What if I have more than one config file?

Comment: I believe it would be `$this->mergeConfigFrom( __DIR__.'/config/file.php', 'package.file');`